# Why does my "mousemove" event listener triggers continuously only with anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener

Here is my code snippet:

```
frame_box.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){ 
    setOrigin(event);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){mousemove_handler(event),false); }, true)
```

It works the way I want it to work, but since I want to remove the listener later on, I cannot use anonymous functions (right?). But when I simply cut out the anonymous function wrap... :

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove_handler(event),false);
```

...the mouse move event doesnt trigger every few milliseconds but only once.

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Your code will keep adding the mousemove listener whenever the frame_box is clicked, meaning the mousemove_handler will be executed multiple times. Also, instead of removing the listener, you can turn a global variable true / false. Inside the listener you check the variable and simply `return false` if the listener is supposed to be deactivated.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jLyf4koz/

Comment: Thank you Chris for the "workaround" and the example code, I'll do it this way. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove_handler, false);
```

if you type

```
 document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove_handler(), false);
```

you call the function and bind the RETURN